# vuejs get data on <input type="hidden"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I try get data "Id" of my list the script get Id wrong.

I need Id that field. but my return is wrong

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id"  v-mode="todo.Id">
```

I stay use a hidden because I not how get that id without use hidden imput

```
</tr>
    <tr  v-for="todo in todos">
    <td>{{todo.filial}} Id {{todo.Id}}<input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id"  v-mode="todo.Id"></td>


    Deletar: function (event){
        alert($('#Id').val());
        /*$.post( "Salva.php", { textoDoFormulario: this.todosView.Id, status: "delete"  } );
        $.get('t2576.php', function(resp) {
                todosView.todos = resp;
        }, "json");*/
    },
```

Comment: Add proper code. Currently it looks garbage to me.

Comment: You probably want `v-model`, not `v-mode`, for starters.

Answer (score -1):

v-model doesn't work on hidden input. [related issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1194)